# How do I rename files without a right-click?

Tags: nautilus, files, rename

I am a new user to Linux and am using Ubuntu 12.04. I would like to know if there is any way to rename files by clicking on file name and not using right click.Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Select (click on) the file, and press <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. The filename will be highlighted as shown below; simply type the new name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to rename the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your HUD is enabled, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show its prompt, write *rename* (or the equivalent translation in your Ubuntu idiom) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to rename. Of course, you have to select the file and/or folder before.