# Single-click file rename in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

Is there a way to configure Nautilus (Files) to open the "rename" mode for a file by single-clicking it (like in Windows) instead of opening the context menu and searching for the "rename" option?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and coming from older versions; I hoped the issue had been addressed in the new version.

I found a solution to do it via the <kbd>F2</kbd> key, but I'm looking for a mouse-based single-click modification:

[Keyboard Shortcut to Rename File in GUI (Other Than F2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696866/keyboard-shortcut-to-rename-file-in-gui-other-than-f2/697012#697012)

Comment: so am i.  i want the "slow" double click to open file rename mode  (windows style).

Comment: Personally I hate slow-double-click to rename, so I wouldn't call this an issue per se, more of a missing feature.

Comment: Related: [How do I rename files without a right-click?](https://askubuntu.com/q/168406/301745)

Comment: Bug report: [Cannot rename by clicking on a file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/48671)

Comment: I think [some versions of Nemo have this](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/520#issuecomment-33993914), and I think it's called "[Click twice with a pause in between to rename items](https://i.imgur.com/ZfwF86y.png)" (ignore the red box in this screenshot).